# Как правильно сверстать эту секцию?

Tags: html, css

У меня вышло вот это. Я так понимаю это в корне не верно. Подскажите в какую сторону копать как это сделать правильно?

```css
.main_mnu {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  min-height: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.main_mnu ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.main_mnu li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 4%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.main_mnu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #121212;
}
.main_mnu li a:hover {
  color: #76a403;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #76a403;
}

.screen_one {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  min-height: 525px;
  background-image: url(http://s016.radikal.ru/i337/1609/7a/671f80a0b1cbt.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.offer {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 110px;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.69;
}
.offer h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 5px 5px black;
  padding: 22px 0;
}
.offer h2 span {
  color: #76a403;
}

.special {
  width: 450px;
  height: 237px;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.69;
  bottom: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav class="main_mnu">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 ">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="/">О компании</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Каталог</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Как мы работаем</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">География</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Кто мы</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">Контакты</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</nav>
<section class="screen_one">
 <div class="offer">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <h2>Поставки <span>всех видов кормов</span> для сельскохозяйственных животных  
в различных отраслях животноводства <span>по всей России</span></h2>

    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-mb-6">
    <div class="special">

    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Вы бы хоть пример дали того, что должно быть.

Comment: Извините картинка не загрузилась. http://s010.radikal.ru/i314/1609/d1/08d495de0c42.jpg Я хотел эту секцию как-то с помощью бустртапа состряпать, но получилось непонятно что. Пробуду вот по старинке https://jsfiddle.net/oaeybv0m/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если на быструю руку, то например так:

```css
.navbar {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  float: none;
}

.navbar-nav > li > a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
}

.nav > li > a:hover, 
.nav > li > a:focus {
  color: #77a407;
  background: transparent;
}

.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  background: #77a407;
}

.intro {
  background: url(http://widefon.com/_ld/126/89465606.jpg) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  
  min-height: 420px;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

.intro.container-fluid {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.title {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.52);
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.title h2 {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 2rem auto;
}


.box span,
.title span {
  color: #77a407;
}

.btn-submit {
  background: #77a407;
  border: 1px solid #77a407;
  color: #fff;
  width: 17%;
}

.my-form {
  background: rgba(4, 4, 4, 0.78);
  padding: 2rem;
}

.my-form.form-inline .form-group input {
  width: 100%;
}

.box { 
  padding: 3rem 3rem 3rem;
  font-size: 2rem;
  position: relative;
}

.box p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  color: #fff;
}

.box:after {
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  left: 0rem;
  right: 0rem;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.52);
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .my-form.form-inline .form-group {
    width: 25.75%;
    margin-right: 1%;
  }  
  
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .box { 
    padding: 3rem 3rem 100px;
  }
  
  .box:after {
    left: -3rem;
    right: 3rem;
    transform: skew(155deg);
  }
  
  .fix.container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="col-md-12 nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="col-md-2 text-center active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li class="col-md-2 text-center"> <a href="#">Page 1</a> </li>
            <li class="col-md-2 text-center"><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
            <li class="col-md-2 text-center"><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            <li class="col-md-2 text-center"><a href="#">Page 4</a></li>
            <li class="col-md-2 text-center"><a href="#">Page 5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
  
  <div class="container-fluid intro">
    <div class="title text-center">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor <span>sit amet</span>, consectetur adipisicing elit. <span>Placeat, aliquid.</span></h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="container fix">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="box">
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <span>consectetur</span> adipisicing elit. Reiciendis ullam a ipsum autem ipsa commodi excepturi officiis <span>nobis maxime</span> quis.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container fix">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <form class="form-inline text-center my-form" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail2">Email</label>              
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail2" placeholder="Enter email">              
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputPassword2">Пароль</label>              
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword2" placeholder="Password">              
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputText2">Text</label>              
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleInputText2" placeholder="Text input" >              
            </div>             
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-submit">Войти</button>   
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

[ПРИМЕР НА JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/jucowa/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: зашибись. Спасибо